# Is it possible to make glassfish3/eclipselink to log bind varibles values into log file?

Tags: jpa, glassfish, logging, eclipselink

I have application deployed on GlassFish 3.1.1. I use Eclipselink as JPA provider. Is it possible to make glassfish/eclipselink to log bind variables' values in sql queries to file?

At the moment I have result

```
[#|2011-11-21T18:49:39.807+0600|FINE|glassfish3.1.1|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/dof-web-1.0/WEB-INF/classes/_mainPU.sql|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=null;MethodName=null;|SELECT ID, ABIS_BANK_ID, ADDRESS, IS_AGR_EXIST, AUX_VALUE, BIK, CDATE, COUNTRY, CUSER, ENG_VALUE, IIN, KAZ_VALUE, KPP, RUS_VALUE, SWIFT, UDATE, UUSER FROM SCHEMANAME.BANK WHERE (IS_AGR_EXIST = ?) ORDER BY RUS_VALUE ASC
    bind => [1 parameter bound]|#]
```

But I have to get variable value.

logging.properties content:

```
javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.level=INFO
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.logFormatDateFormat=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH\:mm\:ss.SSSZ
javax.enterprise.system.ssl.security.level=INFO
org.apache.jasper.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.flushFrequency=1
org.eclipse.persistence.session.level=FINER
javax.enterprise.system.tools.backup.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.corba.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.resource.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.core.classloading.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.jta.level=INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINEST
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.file=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/server.log
javax.enterprise.system.webservices.saaj.level=INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.XMLFormatter
javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.level=INFO
org.apache.catalina.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationTimelimitInMinutes=0
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.mdb.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.timing.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.core.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationOnDateChange=false
org.apache.coyote.level=INFO
ShoalLogger.level=CONFIG
javax.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.taglib.level=INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=50000
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.logtoConsole=false
javax.enterprise.resource.javamail.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.webservices.rpc.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.container.web.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.util.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.level=FINEST
javax.org.glassfish.persistence.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.jms.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationLimitInBytes=2000000
javax.enterprise.system.core.config.level=INFO
org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.core.security.level=INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=%h/java%u.log
javax.enterprise.system.container.cmp.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.SyslogHandler.useSystemLogging=false
javax.enterprise.resource.sqltrace.level=FINE
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.webservices.registry.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.core.selfmanagement.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.formatter=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter
.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.maxHistoryFiles=0
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.validator.util.Version=warn
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=1
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.managedbean.level=INFO
org.glassfish.admingui.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.jdo.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.core.naming.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.retainErrorsStasticsForHours=0
```

Eclipselink version

```
[#|2011-11-21T18:49:31.333+0600|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/dof-web-1.0/WEB-INF/classes/_mainPU|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504|#]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title says "Toplink", but your logs reveal "Eclipselink". Please correct that.

Have you tried adding the property to `persistence.xml`, as the [Eclipse wiki advises](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging):

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
```

Perhaps it will work as well in the `logging.properties`?

Answer (score 1):

You can set this through,

```
"eclipselink.logging.parameters"="true"
```

in your `persistence.xml`.

Actually it should be true by default for log level < CONFIG, but it seems Glassfish's usage of Java logging is confusing this.  Please log a bug on EclipseLink that the correct logger's level should be used in checking the default parameter logging.